how to detect slow coroutine in asio
I found some socket timeout in my app which use asio and c++20 awaitable.
I think perhaps I mix some block code in the coroutine. So I want to find it.
I write a custom executor, just wrap execute / dispath / defer / post like this:
    class executor_proxy_t
    {
    public:
        using executor_execute_t = cfgo::unique_function<void()>;
        using fun_t = std::function<void(executor_execute_t)>;
        
        template<typename F>
        requires std::convertible_to<F, fun_t>
        executor_proxy_t(F && f): fun_(std::make_shared<fun_t>(std::forward<F>(f))) {}
        executor_proxy_t(const executor_proxy_t & other) noexcept: fun_(other.fun_) {}
        executor_proxy_t & operator=(const executor_proxy_t & other) noexcept
        {
            fun_ = other.fun_;
            return *this;
        }
        executor_proxy_t(executor_proxy_t && other) noexcept: fun_(std::move(other.fun_)) {}
        executor_proxy_t & operator=(executor_proxy_t && other) noexcept
        {
            fun_ = std::move(other.fun_);
            return *this;
        }
        void operator()(executor_execute_t f) const
        {
            (*fun_)(std::move(f));
        }
        friend bool operator==(const executor_proxy_t & a, const executor_proxy_t & b) noexcept
        {
            return a.fun_ == b.fun_;
        }
        friend bool operator!=(const executor_proxy_t & a, const executor_proxy_t & b) noexcept
        {
            return !(a == b);
        }
    private:
        std::shared_ptr<fun_t> fun_;
    };

    template<asio_executor Executor>
    class wrappable_executor
    {
        template<typename OtherExecutor>
        requires std::convertible_to<OtherExecutor, Executor>
        explicit wrappable_executor(OtherExecutor && executor, executor_proxy_t proxy): 
            m_executor(std::forward<OtherExecutor>(executor)),
            m_proxy(std::move(proxy))
        {}
        ...
        template <typename Function>
        requires asio::traits::execute_member<const Executor &, Function>::is_valid
        void execute(Function&& f) const
        {
            m_executor.execute([proxy = m_proxy, f = std::move(f)] () mutable {
                proxy(std::move(f));
            });
        }

        template <typename Function, typename Allocator>
        void dispatch(Function&& f, const Allocator& a) const
        {
            m_executor.dispatch([proxy = m_proxy, f = std::move(f)] () mutable {
                proxy(std::move(f));
            }, a);
        }

        template <typename Function, typename Allocator>
        void post(Function&& f, const Allocator& a) const
        {
            m_executor.post([proxy = m_proxy, f = std::move(f)] () mutable {
                proxy(std::move(f));
            }, a);
        }

        template <typename Function, typename Allocator>
        void defer(Function&& f, const Allocator& a) const
        {
            m_executor.defer([proxy = m_proxy, f = std::move(f)] () mutable {
                proxy(std::move(f));
            }, a);
        }

    private:
        Executor m_executor;
        executor_proxy_t m_proxy;
    }

void proxy_fun(sr::executor_proxy_t::executor_execute_t fun)
{
    using namespace std::chrono;
    std::cout << "before fun" << std::endl;
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();
    fun();
    auto dur = high_resolution_clock::now() - start;
    std::cout << "after fun" << std::endl;
    std::cout << "use " << duration_cast<microseconds>(dur).count() * 1.0 / 1000 << " ms" << std::endl;
}

auto async_return_int(int v) -> asio::awaitable<int>
{
    std::cout << "async_return_int " << v << std::endl;
    co_return v;
}

int main()
{
    asio::io_context io_ctx;
    sr::wrappable_executor<asio::io_context::executor_type> executor (io_ctx.get_executor(), proxy_fun);
    asio::co_spawn(executor, []() -> asio::awaitable<void> {
        std::cout << "1" << std::endl;
        co_await async_return_int(0);
        std::cout << "2" << std::endl;
        co_await async_return_int(1);
        std::cout << "3" << std::endl;
        co_await async_return_int(2);
        std::cout << "4" << std::endl;
    }, asio::detached);
    io_ctx.run();
    return 0;
}


And here is the output:
before fun
1
async_return_int 0
2
async_return_int 1
3
async_return_int 2
4
after fun
use 1.081 ms
before fun
before fun
after fun
use 0.002 ms
after fun
use 0.602 ms

It seems that all tree co_await is executed together, and cost more than 1 ms. async_return_int just return a int. it should not cost so much time. So I think executor.execute() include some schedule time.
To summarize, my wrappable_executor is not good enough for my needs. Do you guys have any better ideas? And I need the source location of the slow code as well. I don't know how to send the source location to the detect code.
